# sqlite - есть ли что-то аналогичное удобное, но компактнее

Tags: python, sqlite

Перешел на sqlite после dbf. Храню там около 500 000 записей, числовые значения по датам. стало в разы удобнее пользоваться на python, доставать, искать, фильтровать, но я ожидал, что и размер станет меньше. Но увы, размер даже возрос, было 25мб (dbf) стало 30 мб (sqlite).
Скажите какие есть варианты как оптимизировать sqlite ? ваккум уже использовал. остановился размер на 30 мб. Открываю sqlite в текстовом редакторе и смотрю там довольно "широко" данные хранятся. Как можно все это заставить сжимать? например дата хранится 'yyyy-mm-dd' строкой.
типы я выбрал для ключа id int, для даты date, для значений записей real, для флагов, int(1)

Сама база сжатая в zip занимает 7мб - ужалась до 30%.
Можно ли как то приблизится к такому значению?

Comment: Если только читать (или только добавлять), то можно сделать свой бинарный формат, либо что-то готовое вида HDF5. Если обновлять в середине - тут стоимость собственного решения сильно велика по сравнению с выигранным местом.

Comment: вся проблема из за лишних 5MB?!!!

Comment: почему 5 то? если ужать то лишних больше половины. да и если смотреть содержимое. почему он дату целиком хранит.
Свой бинарный формат хорошо конечно. Но хочется хорошее готовое отлаженное решение. тем более с sql запросами.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить вынести даты в отдельный справочник, а в основную таблицу писать `id` дат. Вряд ли же у вас там за 500_000/365 ~= 1500 лет данные, наверняка даты сильно повторяются, их понадобится не очень много и `id` даты можно сделать достаточно компактным типом. Да, это немного усложнит работу с базой, но, возможно, даст хорошую экономию места.

Вполне возможно, что и другие сущности у вас сильно повторяются, например, значения. Если уж экономить на спичках, то можно и в эту сторону посмотреть - создать ещё и справочник значений.

Comment: ну это конечно тот еще геморой) дату в int хранить и в другой таблице. А может timestamp есть. Чтобы дата занимала не 10 байт а меньше. Может я не тот тип выбрал. у меня тип date сейчас